# SVG text textlength not working on Mobile Safari

Tags: svg, mobile-safari

Noticed my SVG text was looking different on different browsers.
After some testing, found that Mobile Safari isn't respecting textLength set on an svg text element.

```
<text dy="10" textLength="240" fill="red">
```

[image]

Here is the SVG code.

```
<svg class="passportStamp stampEffectClass" width="120" height="120" viewBox="0 0 206 206">
  <circle cx="103" cy="103" r="100" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="3"></circle>
  <circle cx="103" cy="103" r="90" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="3"></circle>

  <text x="103" y="70" text-anchor="middle" fill="red" stroke-width="2px" alignment-baseline="middle" font-variant="all-small-caps" font-size="31" font-weight="bold">textLength</text>
  <text x="103" y="100" text-anchor="middle" fill="red" alignment-baseline="middle" font-variant="all-small-caps" font-size="45">100</text>
  
  <path id="textCircle" d="M28,103a75,75 0 1,0 150,0a75,75 0 1,0 -150,0" fill="none" stroke="none"></path>
  <text dy="10" textLength="240" fill="red">
    <textPath xlink:href="#textCircle">textLength Chrome vs iOS</textPath>
  </text>
  
  <g fill="red" transform="scale(0.15) translate(550 800)">
    <path d="m2,106h28l24,30h72l-44,-133h35l80,132h98c21,0 21,34 0,34l-98,0 -80,134h-35l43,-133h-71l-24,30h-28l15,-47"></path>
  </g>
  
  <g fill="red" transform="translate(90,30)">
    <path d="M14.128 1.79003C13.1305"></path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Looking at cross browser fallback options, but haven't found any way to make it work yet.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem. Safari wants the textlength to be set on the textPath.

**Solution**, set the textlength on both the `text` for Chrome, and `textPath` for Safari.

Was tipped off by [this issue on the great github project webcompat](https://github.com/webcompat/web-bugs/issues/57893), which reported similar issues.

Code:

```
    <svg width="205" height="205" class="stampEffectClass isolate">
      <circle cx="103" cy="103" r="100" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="3"></circle>
      <circle cx="103" cy="103" r="90" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="3"></circle>
      <text x="103" y="70"
        text-anchor="middle" fill="red" stroke-width="2px" alignment-baseline="middle" font-variant="all-small-caps"
        font-size="45" font-weight="bold">textLength</text>
        
        <text x="103" y="100" text-anchor="middle" fill="red"
        alignment-baseline="middle" font-variant="all-small-caps" font-size="45">240</text>
        
      <path id="textCircle" d="M28,103a75,75 0 1,0 150,0a75,75 0 1,0 -150,0" fill="none" stroke="none"></path>
      <text dy="10"
        textLength="240" fill="red">
        <textPath xlink:href="#textCircle" textLength="240">textLength Chrome vs iOS</textPath>
      </text>
      <g fill="red" transform="scale(0.15) translate(550 800)">
        <path d="m2,106h28l24,30h72l-44,-133h35l80,132h98c21,0 21,34 0,34l-98,0 -80,134h-35l43,-133h-71l-24,30h-28l15,-47">
        </path>
      </g>
      <g fill="red" transform="translate(90,30)">
        <path
          d="M14.128 1.79003C13.1305">
        </path>
      </g>
    </svg>
```

Image showing fix:
[image]